# Keep focus on input until gets value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a web site that will get an input value from a bar code reader. I need to keep the input field focus until it gets the value. I used `<input onBlur="this.focus()">` and some variations using functions, but won't work. I'd prefer not using jQuery, but it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do might be perfectly fine in your specific use case, but please don't do this if it isn't really, absolutely necessary. It is very annoying, if users can't control the focus anymore. Having said that, you could do it like this:

```
<input onBlur="if (this.value == '') { var field = this; setTimeout(function() { field.focus(); }, 0); }" type="text">
```

You probably should put this in a separate function.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon. It worked perfectaly. And don't worry, I'm a user too and I know how annoying is it...

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :) I just wanted to put in a "warning" to any future readers not to do this. There are already enough bad practices out there.